# Cannot show the labels of factor correct

Tags: r

I had defined major into factor,
but the labels still shows "I" and "D", and not in the correct order.
What is the problem?

[image]

```
major <- factor(major, levels = c("I","D"), labels = c("Information", "Documentation"))

major
[1] Information   Information   Information   Information   Information   Information  
[7] Information   Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation Information  
[13] Information   Information   Information   Information   Documentation Documentation
[19] Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation
[25] Documentation Documentation Documentation Information   Information   Information  
[31] Information   Information   Information   Information   Information   Information  
[37] Information   Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation
[43] Information   Information   Information   Information   Information   Information  
[49] Information   Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation Documentation
Levels: Information Documentation

ggplot(kaoyan,aes(year,score1))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~major)
```

Comment: `major` is not in `kaoyan`?

Comment: Is there a separate column named "major" inside the `kaoyan` data.frame?

Comment: @user2974951 thank you! I got it, I had not set the kaoyan$major into factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major variable that you were transforming was not in your data frame, it was a different separate variable.